# Fast multi-threaded Set implementation that needs no read/write-sync

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, dictionary, set

I'm looking for a fast Set or Map implementation that has a weaker thread-safety in favor of speed.

The idea is to have a data structure that can quickly be checked whether it contains a (Long) entry at best without thread-synchronization. It is okay if a new entry that is written by another thread becomes visible to the other threads at a later time.

I know already that the non thread-safe HashSet Java standard implementation may disrupt the datastructures while inserting a new element and a reader thread ends up in an endless loop during lookup.

I also know that whenever the writing methods are using synchronized blocks, all reader methods should be synchronized as well in a multi-threaded implementation.

So my ultimate goal is to find a possibility to insert in O(1) and lookup in O(1) where

- the inserts might get queued in some way for bulk insert at a sync-point (if there is no other possibility)
- the read does not get stuck but should not need to wait (for any writers)
- the inserted element should be visible to any subsequent reads of the thread that added the element (which might prevent the aforementioned queue)

I am experimenting with Longs that represent hash-codes mapping to Lists of usually one, sometimes two or more entries.

Is there a way to achieve this e.g. via an array and compare-and-exchange and which is faster than using the `ConcurrentHashMap`?

How would a sketched implementation look like given that the input consists of node-ids (type Long) of a graph that is traversed with multiple threads that somehow exchange information which nodes have been visited already (as described in the list above).

I really appreciate any comments and ideas,
thanks in advance!

*Edit*: Added extended information on the actual task that I am doing some hobby-research on and which led me to asking the question here in the forum.

Comment: "weaker thread-safety"? Thread safety either exists, either does not. Did you look at `ConcurrentHashMap`?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, yes the implementation must not be thread-safe in the sense of synchronized access, but it should not create endless loops either. I considered ConcurrentHashMap 'to slow' and am looking for a faster way since the consistency is not needed.

Comment: what is your "speed" requirement?  how frequent are writes related to reads?

Comment: @jtahlborn, am using 8 threads here, one per cpu-core and each thread will add values while the other 7 plus the thread itself will frequently check if a hashcode is present. The algorithm checks if a hashcode is present and adds the value if it is not there yet (like compute does). I guess it is one 'cache-hit' out of 20. I should measure this, indeed. I'm looking for ways to improve the speed beyond synchronized by maybe using some techniques that avoid the synchronization and e.g. use cmpxchg which allows atomic operations without barriers or mutexes.

Comment: this is much more interesting then I expected after initially reading the question. it seems that you want some kind of eventual consistency here. The fact that you mention "the inserted element should be visible to any subsequent reads of the thread that added the element", means you could use release/acquire semantics, but I have not tried (or seen) such implementations in java.

Comment: @Eugene, yes eventual consistency would be the right term to use. The system actually traverses a graph via a multi-threaded implementation and it isn't bad if a node is visited more than once, as long as the 'visited' information is propagated sooner or later.

Comment: to be fair, you should really measure, first. I have serious doubts that a concurrent structure like `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()` is going to be the bottleneck.

Comment: what is your expected set size?

Comment: @jtahlborn I have sets of 130k elements for testing purposes. I've just tried the ConcurrentHashMap and it takes 4600ms on 8 cores with 8 threads vs 10000ms on a single thread. To me this looks like there is potential for optimization.

Comment: have you tried increasing the "parallelization" for the ConcurruentHashMap?

Comment: @jtahlborn, well I don't use the parallelism threshold in map.foreach if it is this what you meant. The code uses `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cores);` and each submitted task now uses the same ConcurrentHashMap and calls `compute`.
- actually I found that if I use 8 regular HashMaps one for each thread and if I keep the changes in a list for copying them to the other maps after each run this takes pretty much the same time (i.e half of the time using a single thread as above) to compute the graph traversal.

Comment: no, i meant increasing the `concurrencyLevel` for the ConcurrentHashMap (the number of separate locks used internally https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#ConcurrentHashMap-int-float-int-

Comment: @jtahlborn thanks for the hint, didn't know that this option existed and should've read the spec more carefully. I set this option to `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` and it is still as quick as using separate maps for each thread and copying the new entries of each map into the other maps after some iterations. Now waiting for this question to eventually be reopened.

Comment: @jtahlborn the concurrencyLevel is obsolete since Java 8. It has no impact on a `ConcurrentHashMap ` with a reasonable initial capacity.

Comment: I can not reproduce you results. When I create 130k Long objects and add them to a Set created with `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet(130_000)` , I'm not getting anywhere near you four seconds. 50 milliseconds is already a large value for this operation. Best case I had was ~3 ms for the entire operation (with 8 threads).

Comment: @Holger, thanks for trying this out, to summarize my technical efforts on this topic; The algorithm attempts to visit all nodes in a directed acyclic graph. To avoid visiting the nodes in the graph multiple times it uses a Map with nodeid as key and list of values with additional info. I'd like to use threads to sweep through the graph in parallel and its ok for me if a node is visited twice if a thread doesn't know yet that it has been visited earlier. So the timing refers to the complete graph traversal here.

Comment: The set implementation surely isn’t the problem here. What happens with a node already in the map regarding (sub)traversal? A) it’s not traversed. This can lead to threads being responsible for very large subgraphs alone while other threads are idle. B) it’s not processed but still traversed. This can lead to threads traversing large graphs without finding nodes to process. In either case, less than optimal thread utilization.

Comment: @Holger, A) currently when one thread runs out of node-ids in the processing list of work-items an item is simple dequeued from the list of another thread and added to the empty list to keep it busy. B) I didn't quite get your point, the node is first processed if it is not in the set of visited nodes already and then all directed edges are traversed and the nodes found are added for processing. I'm searching for a way to allow the duplicate processing of such a node in case one thread saw it earlier but another thread does not yet have knowledge about the fact that it was already visited

Comment: Since the question is closed for nine days already, I suggest to leave it as is, thanks for your input!

Comment: There are votes to re-open and think, if you’re focusing on your actual problem of efficient multi-threaded graph traversal, rather than asking for an efficient set implementation (as the set is not the issue here), it has even better chances for getting reopened. It’s interesting to read now, that there are queues of work-items to process, which makes the set even less relevant. So this turns out to be a perfect example of [the xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)